# How to join two collections (custom collection with customer collection) in magento?

Tags: magento

I am creating a module in which I tried to `JOIN` two Collection.

1st is custom collection `('custom/custom')` and second is `('customer/customer')`, I want to filter the collection based on a custom customer attribute '**pushnotification**'.

**What so far I did :**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('cust' => 'customer_entity'),
        'cust.entity_id = main_table.user_id');
```

**Output**

```
 [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 1
        [registration_id] => 123456
        [device_type] => 0
        [entity_id] => 1
        [entity_type_id] => 1
        [attribute_set_id] => 0
        [website_id] => 1
        [email] => deepak@gmail.com
        [group_id] => 1
        [increment_id] => 
        [store_id] => 1
        [created_at] => 2015-10-03 13:26:37
        [updated_at] => 2015-10-22 06:25:33
        [is_active] => 1
        [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
```

**My query :** How can I JOIN **custom ('custom/custom')** collection with **customer ('customer/customer')** collection filter based on attribute `pushnotification`?